# Write full subordintion chain

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression, self-join

I have the following Student table

```
id  boss_id name    age
1   NULL    NEW_A   10
2   1       NEW_A   12
3   1       NEW_A   14
4   3       NEW_A   16
5   3       NEW_A   18
6   5       NEW_A   20
7   1       NEW_B   22
8   1       NEW_B   24
9   8       NEW_B   26
10  9       NEW_B   28
11  4       NEW_B   44
```

The following query

```
select s.id as student, boss.id as boss from Student s, Student boss
where s.boss_id = boss.id --and s.id = 11
order by s.id
```

retrieves

```
2   1
3   1
4   3
5   3
6   5
7   1
8   1
9   8
10  9
11  4
```

I want to return full chain subordination

for example for student 11 it should be

```
student_id    boss_id
11              4
4               3
3               1
```

Does sql allow to write query according my needs ?

Comment: what is the dbms being used?

Comment: @vkp I use ms sql, but I would prefer universe sql

Comment: the thing is the universe is too big, and no every one use the same tools

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza at least sql 99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  T.id, T.boss_id
    From    YourTable   T
    Where   T.Id = 11
Union All
    Select  T.id, T.boss_id
    From    YourTable   T
    Join    Cte         C   On  C.boss_id = T.id
                            And T.boss_id Is Not Null
)   
Select  id, boss_id
From    Cte
```

---

```
id  boss_id
11  4
4   3
3   1
```

<kbd>**[`SQL Fiddle Live Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95611/1/0)**</kbd>